# Harmonic function with boundary value 0 except one point

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

Let $\Delta=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$ Assume $u\in C(\overline{\Delta}\setminus \{1\})$ such that it is harmonic in $\Delta$ and $u(\xi)=0$ for $\xi\in S^1\setminus \{1\}$.

> (a) Find an example $u$ as above which is not identically 0
>
> (b) Find some nontrivial condition which guarantees $u$ to be $0$. Make your condition as sharp as possible.
>
> (c) Find all such nonnegative $u$'s

How would you do all of these? Using Poisson kernel?

Comment: You might consider the conformal equivalence between the disk and the upper half plane, mapping the real line to the unit circle except $\{1\}$. I am sure you can find lots of nontrivial harmonic functions on the upper half plane vanishing on the real axis.